# Which type does not derive from DependencyObject?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

in other words, Which type is not capable of having a Dependency property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any class not deriving from `DependencyObject`. Honestly, I don't see the reason to list them. Just have a look in the Object Browser.

Comment: I think maybe he was wondering what sort of classes can't have `DependencyProperty`s.

Comment: A class needs to derive from `DependecyObject` to have a `DependencyProperty`. "[...] whereas DependencyObject as a base class enables objects to use the dependency properties." see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx

Comment: A common base class for classes derived from ContentElement, Freezable, or Visual. (UIElement, another base element class, has a class hierarchy that includes Visual.) I suppose u are right. thanks